# Problema con array y Twig symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony2, twig

Tengo un problema entre el controlador de una aplicación y una plantilla twig, lo que realizo es la conversión de un campo de una fila de la base de datos a **UTF8**, para después mandar un array a la vista y ese campo me salga bien formateado.

Código de controlador y de twig :

```
foreach ($articles as $key):
        foreach ($key as $a => $b):
            $articles1[] = array($a,utf8_decode($b));
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

**article** es un array que me devuelve una consulta a la base de datos y
que contiene lo siguiente:

```
$articles1 = array(4) {
         [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "titulo" [1]=> string(43) "texto1" }
         [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "url" [1]=> string(43) "example-url" }
         [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "titulo" [1]=> string(43) "texto2" }
         [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "url" [1]=> string(43) "example-url2" }
}
```

El problema ocurre cuando paso este array a la vista:

```
return $this->render('bundlecualquiera:articles:slide.html.twig', **array('articles1'=>$articles1));
```

Esta es la vista donde aparentemente recorro el array y saco únicamente de ejemplo el título:

```
**{% for user in articles1 %}
   {{user.titulo}} 
 {% endfor %}****
```

El error que muestra es:
***Key "titulo" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in ..(plantilla).***

**Debería de quedar así:**

```
$articulos = array(2) {
            [0]=> array(3) {
                 ["url"]=> string(16) "url-exmple"
                 ["titulo"]=> string(47) "titulo de articulo" 
                 ["imagen"]=> string(23) "imagen.jpg" } 
            [1]=> array(3) {
                 ["url"]=> string(19) "url-example 2"
                 ["titulo"]=> string(39) "titulo de artiulo"
                 ["imagen"]=> string(20) "imagen.jpg" }
         }
```

Unavez realizada la conversión a UTF8.
Pero queda como muestro mas arriba..:

```
$articles1 = array(4) {
         [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "titulo" [1]=> string(43) "texto1" }
         [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "url" [1]=> string(43) "example-url" }
         [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "titulo" [1]=> string(43) "texto2" }
         [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "url" [1]=> string(43) "example-url2" }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que quede de esta forma el array que me devuelve ?

Lo agradecería muchísimo porque no veo como hacerlo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿podrías hacer un `dump(articles1)` fuera del bucle for y `dump(user)` dentro del for para que podamos ver qué está conteniendo cada variable?

Comment: estás haciendo dos niveles; un array de arrays, por tanto tendrìan que ser dos 'foreach'; en otras palabras y un ejemplo super tonto, serìa como user[0].articulo.

Comment: si veis mas arriba, es como quiero que me quede el array para no tener problemas. @Muriano

Comment: @Muriano en efecto, estaba creando un índice que así no era. Muchas gracias por la aclaración me servirá de guía la próxima vez.

Comment: De nada @otacon070, si la respuesta ha servido para resolver tu caso, te agradecería que lo indicaras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cada iteración de este bucle:

```
foreach ($key as $a => $b):
    $articles1[] = array($a,utf8_decode($b));
endforeach;
```

Estás generando un índice en $articles1

Usa:

```
foreach ($articles as $key):
    $tArray = array();
    foreach ($key as $a => $b):
        $tArray [$a] = utf8_decode($b);
    endforeach;
    $articles1[] = $tArray;
endforeach;
```

Para conseguir la estructura que necesitas.